# How can I add some text besides the curves in a plot?

Tags: python, text, plot

1. I have a vertical line that I would like to have a text label to it. How is it possible?

> matplotlib.pyplot.vlines(q/pow(q+1, 2), 2, 13, colors=('black'), linestyles='solid')

1. I would also like to do the same thing for a group of curves that I have made.

> for c in my_range(C_initial, C_final, 3):
>   x = np.linspace(eta_initial, eta_final, 100)
>   y = c*pow(x, 0.6)
>   plt.plot(x,y)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [text](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text). For your fist example that would be something like:

```
text(0.01,10,'label')
```

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) is more information on annotating a plot.